# FileReader Error when I read a text file

Tags: java, file-io, io

I am trying to store string of array in a text file and read it. But I can't get it working. I am getting NullPointerError.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
   at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
   at in.isuru.justconverter.FileDbTool.readFile(FileDbTool.java:41)
   at in.isuru.justconverter.Test.main(Test.java:10)
```

Here's two classes.

```
package in.isuru.justconverter;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class FileDbTool {

File dataFile;
ArrayList<String> filePath;

public void checkFile(){
    dataFile = new File("db.txt");
    if(dataFile.exists()){
        readFile();
    }else{
        try {
            dataFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Coudn't Create New File!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}

public void readFile(){

    int len;
    try{
        char[] chr = new char[4096];
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(dataFile);
        try {
            while ((len = reader.read(chr)) > 0) {
                buffer.append(chr, 0, len);
            }
          }finally {
             reader.close();
          }
        System.out.println(buffer.toString());
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(buffer.toString(), ",");
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String value = st.nextToken();
            filePath = null;
            filePath = new ArrayList<String>();
            filePath.add(value);
        }

    }catch(IOException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Read Error");
    }
}

public String[] getFilePathArray(){
    readFile();
    return filePath.toArray(new String[filePath.size()]);
}

public File[] getFiles(){
    String[] paths = getFilePathArray();
    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
    for(int i = 0; i < paths.length; i++){

        File file = new File(paths[i]);
        files.add(file);
    }

    return files.toArray(new File[files.size()]);
}

public void eraseFile(){
    dataFile.delete();
}

public void writeFile(String[] stuff){
    try{
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(dataFile, true));
        out.append(stuff + ",");
    }catch(IOException e){

    }
}

public void writeToDb(String[] array){
    writeFile(array);
}

}
```

And main class

```
package in.isuru.justconverter;
```

public class Test {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileDbTool app = new FileDbTool();
    app.checkFile();

}

}
```

Well this is a portion of a swing program. I am trying to use text file as a small database.

Comment: Hmm there is very weird discrepency between the stacktrace you share and your code: the stack trace does not include the call of `checkFile`, just the call to `readFile` straight away. Are you sure you share the most recent stack trace and code?

Comment: your error cannot happen with this code. You must be missing something. Maybe recompile?

Comment: Sorry but that code is broken in many ways. For instance why are you re-creating the filePath ArrayList *inside* of the while loop? Why not use a BufferedReader? Why ignore exceptions? I'd start over, do a little bit at a time, and use the tutorials for guidance as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Line 41 is this:

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(dataFile);
```

so I'd wager that `dataFile` is null here.

However, you do seem to initialize it before calling this method, otherwise the exception would be thrown inside `checkFile`.

Are you sure you are not calling `readFile` directly somewhere without calling `checkFile` first? In any case, this pattern is not a recommended approach, because you are requiring the users of your class to call methods in a specific order.

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace , it seems like you called readfile() directly from main rather than through checkfile() . So dataFile is null since it is not initialized by checkfile . Also the stack trace and the given code doesn't match . When FileReader constructor is called with null argument , it will throw NullPointerException when it reaches FileInputstream constructor . 
Here is the code from jdk source :

```
    public FileInputStream(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
String name = (file != null ? file.getPath() : null);
SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
if (security != null) {
    security.checkRead(name);
}
    if (name == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
fd = new FileDescriptor();
    fd.incrementAndGetUseCount();
open(name);
}
```